# CRM 2015 Microsoft app xpathevaluator' is undefined

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015, xrmservicetoolkit

We are using crm 2015 and it is working without a problem. 
All code is executed correctly in IE and in Chrome. 
But when we try to use the crm app from Microsoft we get the error: 'xpathevaluator' is undefined.

I think it is the **xrmservicetoolkit** that is throwing the error.

```
    if (typeof (node.selectSingleNode) != "undefined") {
        return node.selectSingleNode(xpathExpr);
    } else {
        var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
        var xPathNode = xpe.evaluate(xpathExpr, node, _NSResolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
        return (xPathNode != null) ? xPathNode.singleNodeValue : null;
    }
```

Comment: What app are you referring to? What soft of object are you working on in this code?